# Why reviewers have review audits but not people who post questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that users (new and old) can post questions and answers without having to pass an audit. This results in a important number of bad questions which tend to be downvoted and closed.

I suggest that new users, and users with downvoted or closed questions (the criteria have to be defined), have to pass an audit before they can post questions or answers. It may be 3 questions to audit: 2 bad and one good question. I think it may help users to understand what are bad and good questions. I don't think it should prevent people to post questions if they fail this audit, because it would be too frustrating for the user, but it may still be a first step to force the user to think about what SE expects from its users.

I didn't found any similar questions here.

Comment: @njkt: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People who post questions and answers *do* have review audits.

It's called voting.

If you get too many down-voted questions or answers you will be first warned that you are posting low-quality content and then you will be blocked from posting.

Comment: I agree, but this is a moderation which comes after the content has been posted. I suggest to test users before they post content. I'm sorry but I don't see how your answer adresses this question.

Comment: @A.L - if people post poor quality content this will slow them down and eventually prevent them from posting. What more do you want?

Comment: @ChrisF I assume that A.L wants to keep the poor quality content from taking the community's time by hitting the front page in the first place.

Comment: @tepples - down voting poor questions will prevent future content hitting the front page as the posters will be question blocked

Comment: @ChrisF I imagine that some people don't want to see even a _first_ question from a particular user if it's poor in quality.

Comment: @ChrisF Or to put it in terms of existing SO features, once there are enough active accounts with first post review queue access, hide first posts until they've been approved by someone with queue access.